# how to use foreach loop in order to get only one type of elements?

Tags: php

Does anyone know how to use FOREACH loop to get only all colors or only all fruits?

```
$article = array(
  array( 'color'=>'green','fruit'=>'apples'),
  array( 'color'=>'orange','fruit'=>'oranges '),
  array( 'color'=>'red','fruit'=>'cherry')
);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, we do. Now what have you tried?

Comment: foreach ($article as $a => $b){
    foreach ($b as $c => $d){
 
    echo $c;

 }}, then tried to put list() in foreach arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically want a pivot operation; this hackish approach will do that:

```
$articles = array(
  array( 'color'=>'green','fruit'=>'apples'),
  array( 'color'=>'orange','fruit'=>'oranges '),
  array( 'color'=>'red','fruit'=>'cherry')
);

foreach ($articles as $article) {
  foreach ($article as $type => $value) {
    ${$type}[] = $value;
  }
}

print_r($fruit);
print_r($color);
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/zeXyMb)

Comment: Impressive resolution.

Answer (score 0):

[`array_map`](http://php.net/array-map) would be better suited to this:

```
$colors = array_map(function($a) {return $a['color'];},$article);
$fruits = array_map(function($a) {return $a['fruit'];},$article);
```

Comment: Not if you want both every time, but in separate arrays. In this case, you loop the source array twice using `array_map` in this way.

Comment: Thanks, but  is there a way to do it with foreach?